# Clicking Child Component closes the list that is opened

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have implemented a menu example where when i click on parent menu link all the child elements are visible inside them and when i click on any of the child element it collapses...I have made a demo here http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KzpKrm ...When i click on child link i want the list to be opened like that only and indicate that this link has been selected...Somebody please help

```
  function showmenu(elem) {
        // Clear any currently open menu
        var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");
        if (openMenu) {
            openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
            // Stop if we're just closing the current menu
            if (openMenu === elem) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
        // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
        if (elem.getElementsByTagName("li").length > 0) {
            elem.setAttribute("id", "activeMenu");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I guess u shuld be adding on click handler for the inner list as well

Comment: add `event.stopPropagation()` to click event of ul

Comment: I got `jquery` solution, if you want i'll post it as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check if the actual element clicked is a parent (i.e. has class sectionMenu). If not then return.

You can do this by adding the following code to your javascript:

```
// Checks if element clicked has class sectionMenu. Otherwise return.
var $elementClicked = event.target;
if ($elementClicked.className != 'sectionMenu')
  return;
```

---

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MywYgQ)

```js
  function showmenu(elem) {

    // Checks if element clicked has class sectionMenu. Otherwise return.
    var $elementClicked = event.target;
    if ($elementClicked.className != 'sectionMenu')
      return;

    // Clear any currently open menu
    var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");
    if (openMenu) {
      openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
      // Stop if we're just closing the current menu
      if (openMenu === elem) {
        return;
      }
    }

    // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
    // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
    if (elem.getElementsByTagName("li").length > 0) {
      elem.setAttribute("id", "activeMenu");
    }
  }
```

```css
       img {
         padding-left: 5px;
       }
       #nav {
         height: 100%;
         padding: 20px;
         cursor: pointer;
         border: 3px solid #3e4547;
         box-shadow: 2px 2px 8px #000000;
         border-radius: 3px;
         -moz-border-radius: 3px;
         -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
       }
       ul {
         width: 200px;
         list-style: none;
         margin: 0;
         padding: 5px;
       }
       ul li {
         display: block;
         padding: 0 10px;
         overflow: hidden;
         padding: 5px;
       }
       ul ul {
         display: none;
       }
       ul ul li {
         float: none;
         user-select: #b6ff00;
       }
       #activeMenu ul {
         display: block;
       }
       ul li:hover {
         background-color: #bcbdc1;
       }
       ul ul li:hover {
         background-color: red;
       }
       .arrow {
         background-image: url("./png/2.png");
         transition: 0.3s;
         transform: rotateX(-180deg);
       }
       li.sectionMenu:before {
         content: '\2795';
         font-size: 13px;
         color: #777;
         float: right;
         margin-left: 5px;
       }
       li.sectionMenu#activeMenu:before {
         content: "\2796";
       }
```

```html
<div>
  <ul id="nav">
    <li onclick="showmenu(this)" class="sectionMenu">
      Service
      <ul>
        <li><a> Ro </a> 
        </li>
        <li> <a>List</a> 
        </li>
        <li><a>Service Plan</a> 
        </li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li onclick="showmenu(this)" class="sectionMenu">
      Customer
      <ul>
        <li>New Customer</li>
        <li>customer List</li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li onclick="showmenu(this)" class="sectionMenu">
      Parts
      <ul>
        <li>New Part</li>
        <li>Parts List</li>

      </ul>
    </li>
    <li onclick="showmenu(this)" class="sectionMenu">
      Admin
      <ul>
        <li>New Employee</li>
        <li>Employee List</li>
        <li>Employee Roles</li>
        <li>Employee Work Schedulee</li>
        <li>Holidays</li>

        <li>Employee List</li>

      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: nice and also i need selected listIteam to be applied color ?

Comment: here some problem ,, ul li :hover is applied to all child element, when closing the color will applied to all child element background color are applied  but i don't need it,,  ,,, please give me u r answer ,,,

Comment: @RajaReddy are you referring to the gray background color that is shown when you hover over an opened menu-item?

Answer (score 3):

Well you can add `event.stopPropagation()` to the nested `ul`:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li onclick="showmenu(this)" class="sectionMenu">
        Service
        <ul onclick="event.stopPropagation()">
            <li><a> Ro </a>    </li>
            <li> <a>List</a> </li>
            <li><a>Service Plan</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even U could try this....Remember to pass event argument for the onclick handlers

```
function showmenu(elem,event) {
        // Clear any currently open menu
        event.preventDefault();
        // alert(event.currentTarget.getAttribute("id"))
        var openMenu = document.getElementById("activeMenu");

        if (openMenu) {
            if(openMenu.children[0]==event.target.parentNode)
              return;
            openMenu.removeAttribute("id");
            // Stop if we're just closing the current menu
            if (openMenu === elem) {
                return;
            }
        }

        // Only apply it if the element actually has LI child nodes.
        // OPTIONAL: Will still work without if statement.
        if (elem.getElementsByTagName("li").length > 0) {   
          event.currentTarget.setAttribute("id", "activeMenu");
        }
    }
```

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YqXzom)